# plotting the value from sorted dictionary type in python

Tags: python, sorting, plot

I'd like to do below processes.

1. there is data set as a dictionary type
2. Sort dictionary type
3. plot key(x-axis), value(y-axis)

After sorting, datatype is list consist of key,value.
[(1,550), (3,526) ...and so on]
I don't know how to deal with this kinds of data type.
How to extracted the data from datatype([(1,550), (3,526) ...and so on]) to plot?

```
addr_write = [int(addr) for temp, addr, size, optype, time in pieces_write]
addr_dict = Counter(addr_write)
addr_dict_sorted = sorted(addr_dict.items())

for key, value in addr_dict_sorted.items():
    if value > 50:
        addr_key_sorted.append(key)
        addr_value_sorted.append(value)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(addr_key_sorted, addr_value_sorted)
```

Error message

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addr_dict_sorted` is really a list of tuples.

You should write the for loop as:

```
for key, value in addr_dict_sorted:
   if value > 50:
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
for i in addr_dict_sorted.items():
    if i[1] > 50:
        addr_key_sorted.append(i[0]) #i[0] is key
        addr_value_sorted.append(i[1]) #i[1] is value
```